# How to plot eigenvalues on R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, eigenvalue

I generated 1000 2x2 random matrices with:

> M=lapply(1:1000, function(z) matrix(runif(1000,min=-10,max=10), ncol = 2, nrow = 2))
>   eig=lapply(M, eigen)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the 'values' from a list using `[[` by looping over the elements of `list` with `sapply` and this is done with ***base R***

```
out <- c(sapply(eig, `[[`, "values"))
plot(out)
```

---

Or with `pluck`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(eig, pluck, "values") %>%
     unlist
```

Comment: @Ang I posted the solutio for that

Comment: Oh got it, thank you so much!! Do you know how I could plot all the values instead of manually inputting one at a time?

Comment: Do I have to install all the packages associated with library(tidyverse)? It's coming up as an error when I enter the code

Comment: Sorry for the questions... professor gave limited instructions on this :/

Comment: @Ang Just install `purrr` and `dplyr`.  tidyverse includes a set of packages. I specify it in case I have to use some functions from one of the packages in that

Comment: This is what shows up: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: loadNamespace(name)
  error: there is no package called ‘crayon’

Comment: @Ang  Have you instlaled `install.packages("dplyr"); `install.packages('purrr")` and load those packages

Comment: Yes, I just did but it's telling me I need to download more packages :/

Comment: Ohh got it! Thank you so much...I really appreciate it. Last question: do you know how to determine if each matrix system is a stable node, unstable node, saddle, unstable focus, or center? Like the codes I need to use

Comment: @Ang No, I am not aware of that

Comment: Ah, mm I guess to word it differently -- how can I write a loop for the matrices and make conditional tests?

Comment: @Ang It is not clear.  Can you post as  a new question

Comment: What is the code to make conditional tests of the values (to see if the eigenvalues are real or complex)? Is that a little more clear?

Comment: @Ang You can check `?is.complex`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a base R solution you can turn this into a

```
mats <-  matrix(unlist(lapply(e, function(x) lapply(x, unlist)$values)), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```